# Dynamically setting ImagePath from absolute path in WinRT

Tags: image, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I am trying to create a GridView of dynamically-created Grid items, each of which have their background set as follows:

```
<Grid.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding FilePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Grid.Background>
```

If FilePath is the absolute path to the file that should be loaded for each Grid item, is there a way that I can convert this value to an ImagePath so that the image will load?

I am getting the FilePath using a file picker. The value is then being saved to an ObservableCollection that is loaded when the app starts and displayed by being set as the DataContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `ImagePath` property that I know of and `ImageSource` is not a path or even a `Uri`. You should probably bind your `ImageSource` to a `BitmapImage`. Simply create a new `BitmapImage` and call `SetSource` or `SetSourceAsync` if you want to wait for it to load before updating your image - e.g. to show a placeholder image, a progress indicator or fade in the image.